# Angular JS print div

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that is specifically formatted for printing.
It opens up in a modal popup and is ready to be printed right away.

I am using a jquery plugin that can print a div.

It seems it should be as simple as this

`$($element).printArea();` or `$(element).printArea();` and it works ...sort of...I get the uncompiled version of the directive with `{{stuff}}`

I have tried putting `$(element).printArea();` in both directive and the controller with the same result...

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you are describing it, you should be passing a ready html string to the print method, create an iframe and print that.

An example:

```
.controller('ModalCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
  $scope.open = function (yourdataobject) {
    $scope.items = yourdataobject;

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      template: '<div id="printme"><div class="modal-header">' +
            '<h3 class="modal-title">{{items.name + " " + items.surname }}</h3>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="modal-body">' +
            '<ul class="list-group">' +
               '<li class="list-group-item">' +
                   {{ items.whatever }}' +
                '</li>' +
            '</ul>' +
        '</div></div>' +
        '<div class="modal-footer">' +
            '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" print-div="#printme"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print</a>' +
            '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Close</button>' +
        '</div>',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: '500',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
```

Now this will render your modal with any data and you need the directive to do the print:

```
.directive('printDiv', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      element.bind('click', function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        PrintElem(attrs.printDiv);
      });

      function PrintElem(elem) {
        PrintWithIframe($(elem).html());
      }

      function PrintWithIframe(data) {
        if ($('iframe#printf').size() == 0) {
          $('html').append('<iframe id="printf" name="printf"></iframe>'); 

          var mywindow = window.frames["printf"];
          mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Put a title if you want</title><style>@page {margin: 25mm 0mm 25mm 5mm;font-size:16pt;}</style>' +
                        '</head><body style="font-size:15pt !important;"><div>' +
                        data +
                        '</div></body></html>');

          $(mywindow.document).ready(function(){
            mywindow.print();
            setTimeout(function(){
              $('iframe#printf').remove();
            },
            2000);
          });
        }

        return true;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

That's a modified code from something I am using and know it works, but I could be missing something so let me know.

Comment: On this line `PrintWithIframe($(elem).html());` do you expect `$(elem).html()` to be compiled or still have `{{stuff}}`?